# Is there a way to to run dotnet without generating the bin and obj file?

Tags: .net, .net-core

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro

I am following the above tutorial.

```
$ cat main.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
$ cat main.cs
using System;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `dotnet run` in a directory with the above two files (on macOS), I get `obj` and `bin` directories. Is there a way to run the app without generating the directory?

Answer (score 0):

No, when you run an application the code needs to be compiled into something the computer can actually run. the obj files are a byproduct of the process and the bin is the program itself.  You wouldn't have a program to run without them.  What issues are they causing you?

Comment: Is there a way to config dotnet so that the compiled files are saved somewhere else. I don't want these binaries file put along side the source code. Also, how an windows PE32 file runs on macOS? `$ file bin/Debug/net5.0/main.dll
bin/Debug/net5.0/main.dll: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows`

Comment: the usual best practice is to add them to .gitignore for those using git.  You can change it in the project properties, I don't have visual studio installed right now to check where.  this article may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019  to run a PE32 on mac isn't going too work your need to change the output format and use .net core

Comment: But then how `dotnet run` run the file it is is just a PE32 file?

Comment: macos is not binary compatible with windows. a windows application (PE32) will not run on mac without some form of emulator.  instead you need to output the application in a format mac can run. This article may help you https://stackify.com/cross-platform-net-core-apps/

Comment: `dotnet run` can run on macOS. I don't find any Marc-O files, but just PE32 files. So I am wondering how `dotnet` run the program.